# Qt get text changed

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

Alright, so we have the private slot method [textChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#textChanged) that notifies us when a textEdit object was modified. This implementation is rather robust and informs us when text is inserted with keyboard, with copy and paste, and most of anything else.

Is there anyway, however, to get the actual text that was changed?

Comment: `textEdit.toPlainText()`, perhaps? I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: You might be looking for `QTextEdit::document()` and `QTextDocument` object. The latter emits signals with more detailed information about the change.

Comment: I'm taking a look at the QTextDocument class right now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Igor said, you can use `QTextDocument`. Use this code example:

Do connection:

```
connect( ui->textEdit->document(), SIGNAL(contentsChange(int,int,int)), this, SLOT(change(int,int,int)));
```

Create slot:

```
void MainWindow::change(int pos, int del, int add)
{
    QString added = ui->textEdit->toPlainText().mid(pos,add);
    qDebug() << added;
}
```

In header:

```
  void change(int, int, int);
```

And now you can get text which was pasted or typed in `QTextEdit`

About perfomance. Let's experiment. Write this slot.

```
void MainWindow::clicked(int pos, int del, int add)
{
    QElapsedTimer tmr;
    tmr.start();
    QString added = ui->textEdit->toPlainText().mid(pos,add);
    qDebug() << added;
    qDebug() << "operation tooks" << tmr.elapsed() <<" ms";
}
```

Don't forget `#include <QElapsedTimer>`

Output when I type:

```
operation tooks 0  ms 
"f" 
operation tooks 0  ms 
"d" 
operation tooks 0  ms 
"g" 
operation tooks 0  ms 
"r" 
operation tooks 0  ms 
"d" 
operation tooks 0  ms 
"s" 
operation tooks 0  ms 
"f" 
operation tooks 0  ms
```

Output when I paste text with 7817 characters including spaces:

```
...long text...
operation tooks 0  ms
```

Try it on your computer, I think it is normal efficiency.

Comment: that looks awesome, quite similar to what I found in the docs. Do you have any idea how fast this refreshes though?

Comment: thanks for the edit, I just tried it out on my system and achieved similar results!